# using global variable in matches in drools rules

Tags: drools

I have this rule set in drools.

```
global String ipv4regex;

rule "Initialize global"
  salience 1000
when        
then
   drools.getWorkingMemory().setGlobal( "ipv4regex", "\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b");
end

rule "Router"
when
    r : Router( Ipaddress matches ipv4regex)
then
    System.out.println("Valid ip address");
end
```

Here I am checking for valid ip address, but my rule "Router" is not showing "valid ip address" even if my router ip address is valid. What can be the issue here and how to use global variable in the matches?

Answer (score 3):

The setting of the global variable happens too late. You must do this prior to inserting any facts.

This is due to global variables not being monitored by the rule engine - as opposed to facts, where (announced via modify or update) changes are reconsidered, resulting in a reevaluation.

- Set the global up front in your Java code.
- Use a static final visible in a Java class
- Use another fact containing a String with the regec.
- Use a string literal for the regex.

**Later**

You can declare a fact type for this purpose in DRL:

```
declare Const
   pattern: String
end

rule initConst
salience 1000
when
then
    insert( new Const( "\\b(25[0-5]|2..." ) );
end

rule "Router"
when
    Const( $pat: pattern )
    r : Router( Ipaddress matches $pat )
then
    System.out.println("Valid ip address");
end
```

Comment: When I try to print the value of ipv4regex in Router rule it prints correctly, this means that this variable is initialized properly. I do not want to initialize the global variable in java code as I need them in drl file which will get updated regularly and I do not want to alter and compile code everytime. Probably In future I need to add more such constants, for which adding them in the code require to compile it

Comment: If setting the variable in Java code or using a static final is out, you'll have to use a fact containing this constant (and others). See the update.